# Can't disable logging messages in scrapy scripts

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy (1.5.0) which apparently uses Pillow (5.2.0). When I run my script with `scrapy runspider my_scrapy_script.py` the stdout gets flooded with useless logging messages, e.g.:

```
2018-07-11 14:41:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-07-11 14:41:07 [PIL.Image] DEBUG: Importing BlpImagePlugin
2018-07-11 14:41:07 [PIL.Image] DEBUG: Importing BmpImagePlugin
2018-07-11 14:41:07 [PIL.Image] DEBUG: Importing BufrStubImagePlugin
2018-07-11 14:41:07 [PIL.Image] DEBUG: Importing CurImagePlugin
... many more of the like ...
```

I tried disabling them by settings the logger level like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('PIL.Image').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

etc, it didn't help, I tried to set the root logger level like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

with no effect too, higher levels also don't help

setting `LOG_LEVEL = logging.WARNING` and even `LOG_ENABLED = False` in scrapy settings has no effect too.

if I set `LOG_LEVEL` to `'INFO'` it prints

```
2018-07-11 07:04:42 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOG_ENABLED': False, 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
```

so it looks like the above mentioned flood is produced before the script is loaded

Comment: Have you tried to set `LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'` at scrapy's settings.py?

Comment: @GermanoLodi, yes (didn't help), it seems like the flood is generated before the settings are even loaded

Comment: Please, try to change the `propagate` property, setting `logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Documentation start with an additonal parameter:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

```
--loglevel/-L LEVEL
```

So it could be

```
scrapy runspider my_scrapy_script.py --loglevel WARNING
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging(install_root_handler=True)
logging.disable(50)  # CRITICAL = 50
```

for logging levels = [Python Logging Levels](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

more information => [Scrapy Logging](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)

Another way in spider:

```
  custom_settings = {
    'LOG_ENABLED': False,
  # ... other settings...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Lodi suggested in a question's comment, I could only solve the issue of Scrapy filling the logs with debug messages on production (including all the HTML of the scraped pages) in a Django project using celery, **disabling the propagation of the scrapy logger**. So, what I did is:

settings.py:

```
import logging
if not DEBUG:
    logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False
```

Also, I made my Spider use a logger that derives from 'scrapy' logger, as the `CrawlSpider.logger` isn't a descendant from 'scrapy' logger. So, in this case I used the `scrapy.spiders` logger to log messages from my Spider that inherits from `CrawlSpider`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy.spiders')
```

And then use it with `logger.debug()`, `logger.info()`, etc.

Keep in mind that messages logged with a severity higher than `debug` and `info`, that is: `warning`, `error`, `critical` and `exception` will be propagated altough propagation is disabled at the `scrapy` logger. So, you'll still see the `DropItem` exceptions logged.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable it completely with `LOG_ENABLED=False`. You could also pass settings during scrapy invocation - `scrapy runspider my_scrapy_script.py -s LOG_ENABLED=False`

[Scrapy log documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-level)